Why could I be experiencing an unresolved reference error in Python?
Unresolved reference error with the code below; I've included all the references in the same file, however, I'm still getting an error
class sample:
  @staticmethod
  def some_method():
    print("Hello World")
  @staticmethod
  def some_method2():
     some_method()


Why would you make a method that needs access to other methods in the same class static?

Classes do not create new scopes. some_method2 only looks in the global scope for some_method, not in the body of the sample class definition.

It's a static method so you need to reference it by the class in front as so:
class sample:

  @staticmethod
  def some_method():
      print("Hello World")

  @staticmethod
  def some_method2():
      sample.some_method()

